# Django model error with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am relatively new to Django, but not to python,  My model is trying to use a class (defined in a separate file) in which data is coming from a REST API, the retrieved data is in a nested dictionary.  The code will run fine in python, but when I try it in Django (makemigrations), I get an error:

> File "c:\blah-blah\Clone_PR.py", line 20, in GetFoundOnSelectItems
> values = self._issueEdit["fields"]["customfield_13940"]["allowedValues"]
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I tried using type hints, but that does not work either.

models.py

```
from dal import autocomplete
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import messages
from .Login import jlogin
from .Jira_Constants import ProductionServer, TestServer, StageServer
from .Clone_PR import Issue

jira = None
issue = Issue()

class ClonePrLogin(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    @classmethod
    def LoginToJira(cls):
        global jira
        jira = jlogin(ProductionServer, cls.username, cls.password)

class PrEntry(models.Model):
    prToClone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @classmethod
    def GetIssueAndMeta(cls):
        global issue
        issue.initialize(jira, cls.prToClone)

class ClonePr(models.Model):
    issueKey = issue.issueKey
    issue.GetFoundOnSelectItems()
    foundOnList = issue.foundOnSelectItems
    foundOn = autocomplete.Select2ListChoiceField(choice_list=foundOnList)
```

Clone_PR.py

```
from typing import List, Dict

class Issue():
    def __init__(self):
        self.jiraInst = None
        self.issueKey = ''
        self._issue = None
        self._issueEdit = None
        # self._issueEdit = Dict[str, Dict[str, Dict[str, List[Dict[str, str]]]]]
        self.foundOnSelectItems = []

    def initialize(self, jira, prKey):
        self.jiraInst = jira
        self.issueKey = prKey
        self._issue = jira.issue(prKey)
        self._issueEdit = jira.editmeta(prKey)

    def GetFoundOnSelectItems(self):
        values = self._issueEdit["fields"]["customfield_13940"]["allowedValues"]
        items = [x["value"] for x in values]
        self.foundOnSelectItems = items
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django, running `makemigrations` will load all the modules. You said you're familiar with Python so you should know that the declarations inside the class:

```
class ClonePr(models.Model):
    issueKey = issue.issueKey
    issue.GetFoundOnSelectItems()
    foundOnList = issue.foundOnSelectItems
    foundOn = autocomplete.Select2ListChoiceField(choice_list=foundOnList)
```

will run when the modules load. You're calling `issue.GetFoundOnSelectItems()` at that time, which in turn calls `values = self._issueEdit["fields"]["customfield_13940"]["allowedValues"]`, except that `self._issueEdit = None` upon the initiation of instance Issue above with this line: `issue = Issue()`.

I *highly* recommend you spend some time to become more familiar with how Django starts up an app. The module-level and nested model declarations here are both antipatterns and may cause data issues in the future.